# Adding id attribute inside livewire component

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to make autocomplete / autosuggestion input using laravel livewire component where user will type the input and if match, it will display the suggested option otherwise user just type in the input.

For this case I already create the livewire component. In the component there is one input field and a datalist to display the suggested option. I'm using datalist tag to acquire the same style when using select tag. The problem is, the input field must have an ID. So how do I give a specific id to the input because the component will be used on the same page several times.

```
// livewire component
<div>
<input type="text"
class="form-control form-control-sm"
name="institution"
list="institutions"
wire:model="query"
>
@if(!empty($query))
<datalist id="institutions">
    @foreach($institutions as $institution)
    <option value="{{$institution['name']}}">{{$institution['name']}}</option>
    @endforeach
</datalist>
@endif
```

// livewire controller
    class InstitutionSearchBar extends Component
    {
    public $query; 
    public $institutions;
    public $institutionName;

```
public function mount(){
    $this->query = $this->institutionName;
    $this->institutions = [];
}

public function updatedQuery(){
    $this->institutions = Institution::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
}



public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.applicant.institution-search-bar');
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to So ... you can add id to input file no ?

Comment: Could you please paste  code in post, instead of image of code editor.

Comment: i paste the code already...do you have any idea